# How to calculate Actual Memory usage for java using top linux?

Tags: java, linux, memory, jvm, heap-memory

I need to find out What is the actual memory consumed by Java process in Linux, the tools like visualVM/jconsole shows accurate but I must calculate actual memory used by JVM through top command.

I am looking at PID : 28169 if you look at top (linux)  , it is saying 17.2g ( virtual ) , Res 10g , Shared : 15m . 10G is not possible since I Have given 6G jvmmax to this jvm process  but if I use jvmtop it shows actuate results(matching with visualVM)
can someone shows me how to calculate actual usage of memory using top stats ?

Using JvmTop

JvmTop 0.8.0 alpha - 11:09:08,  amd64, 12 cpus, Linux 2.6.32-57, load avg 0.00
http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop

```
    PID 28169: com.gigaspaces.start.SystemBoot
ARGS: com.gigaspaces.start.services="GSC"
VMARGS: -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemo[...]
VM: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_51
UP: 179:23m #THR: 90   #THRPEAK: 92   #THRCREATED: 3725 USER: evolv
GC-Time:  0: 2m   #GC-Runs: 3353      #TotalLoadedClasses: 23107
CPU:  1.46% GC:  0.00% HEAP:4623m /10240m NONHEAP: 180m / 304m

    TID   NAME                                    STATE    CPU  TOTALCPU BLOCKEDBY
3733 RMI TCP Connection(2210)-10.16       RUNNABLE 14.93%     0.00%
3734 JMX server connection timeout   TIMED_WAITING  0.13%     0.00%
95   GS-directLoadJobListenerPollin  TIMED_WAITING  0.12%     0.14%
94   GS-jobListenerPollingContainer  TIMED_WAITING  0.11%     0.14%
3375 GS-jobListenerPollingContainer  TIMED_WAITING  0.10%     0.55%
93   GS-jobListenerPollingContainer  TIMED_WAITING  0.09%     0.14%
3377 GS-jobListenerPollingContainer  TIMED_WAITING  0.09%     0.56%
81   GS-subJobCompleteListenerPolli  TIMED_WAITING  0.09%     0.14%
3376 GS-jobListenerPollingContainer  TIMED_WAITING  0.08%     0.54%
98   GS-stopJobListenerPollingConta  TIMED_WAITING  0.08%     0.14%
 Note: Only top 10 threads (according cpu load) are shown!
^C-bash-4.1$


using Top : 

top - 11:15:30 up 18 days,  6:34,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 306 total,   1 running, 304 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16332776k total, 15913220k used,   419556k free,   316876k buffers
Swap:  4095996k total,   146452k used,  3949544k free,  3024048k cached




PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
28169 evolv     20   0 17.2g  10g  15m S  2.8 70.3   4493:54 java
28034 evolv     20   0 5690m 289m 7656 S  0.0  1.8  16:31.29 java
28006 evolv     20   0 5821m 286m 7952 S  0.5  1.8  18:16.50 java
2098  root      20   0  272m 145m 4016 S  0.3  0.9  46:51.51 splunkd
2163  root      20   0  128m  40m 1220 S  0.0  0.3   1:05.86 puppet
1879  root      20   0  244m 6660 5036 S  0.0  0.0   1:21.82 sssd_be
```

Comment: What are the command line parameters you are using to start this JVM?  You say that 10Gb is not possible, yet if you look at jvmtop it reports the heap as 4623m /10240m. 10240m is 10Gb, which is why top is reporting resident memory of 10Gb.

Comment: sorry I think i mentioned incorreclty I have given min and Max 10240m  -here is command for java Xms10240m -Xmx10240m , Does it mean top will always shows 10g , even it is not utilizing that amount of memory ,

Comment: Assuming you are using the HotSpot VM from Oracle then yes.  The JVM pre-allocates the virtual memory for the size of the heap you define (in this case min and max are both 10G so that's what gets allocated).  Remember, though, that this is only virtual memory (it's essentially just a range of addresses the JVM can use).  Physical memory pages will only be mapped to those virtual pages when the memory is actually required.  This is why determining, accurately, the amount of memory in use by a JVM is pretty hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jstat` to view your process statistics.

Examples

```
jstat -gc [insert-pid-here]
```

The above would give you an overview of your GC heap.

other commands

```
jstat -gccapacity [insert-pid-here]
jstat -gcutil [insert-pid-here]
```

Comment: I know that way but how can I calculate actual memory using numbers given by top command ?